# XPath: Select root, filter child elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Consider the following XML-document:

```
<inst>
  <ins>
    <id>id_01</id>
    <pos>1</pos>
  </ins>
  <ins>
    <id>id_02</id>
    <pos>1</pos>
  </ins>
</inst>
```

I try to get the following output:

```
<inst>
  <ins>
    <id>id_01</id>
    <pos>1</pos>
  </ins>
</inst>
```

I wrote the following XQuery/XPath-Expression:

`doc('database/data.xml')/inst[ins/id='id_01']`

This does not give the wanted result but the whole document, just as if no filtering condition would be there.. But if i put in id's that are not present in the XML-Document, the result is empty.

I just don't know what is wrong with this statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath you wrote,

```
/inst[ins/id='id_01']
```

says to select the `inst` root element that contain a `ins` child element with a child element whose string value is `"id_01"`.   Since the root of your XML does indeed meet this criteria, it is selected:

```
<inst>
  <ins>
    <id>id_01</id>
    <pos>1</pos>
  </ins>
  <ins>
    <id>id_02</id>
    <pos>1</pos>
  </ins>
</inst>
```

You could instead use this XPath,

```
/inst/ins[id='id_01']
```

to select just this XML,

```
<ins>
  <id>id_01</id>
  <pos>1</pos>
</ins>
```

however, there is no XPath that will select the root element *without* the second `ins` element as you seem to be trying to do.  The reason is that XPath is for *selection*, not transformation of XML.  There is no `inst` element in your XML that can be selected that lacks the second (`id_02`) `ins` element.  If you want to transform XML, use XSLT instead.

Answer (score -2):

You can write something like-

`<inst>{doc('database/data.xml')/inst/ins[id eq "id_01"]}</inst>`
The "value comparison" operators (eq, lt, etc.) are designed for comparing single values, so better to use 'eq'